# Using devise current_user

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, associations

I have a user and an address for example and the relation is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :address
end


class Address< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now when I create an address object, I want to be able to pass through the current_user id and save it to the address model, so in my controller I have

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def new
  @address= current_user.address.new
end

def create
  @address= current_user.address.new(address_params)
   if @address.save
     redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Address Successfully Created'
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end
end

private

def address_params
  params.require(:address).permit(:id, :user_id, :add_1, :add_2, :add_3)
end
```

I can't access the new action at the moment, as the error I am getting is

```
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried `build` instead of `new`?

Comment: still getting the same error (well undefined method build), is it only the new action that is letting me down here?

Comment: I think create will have the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do it like this:

```
def new
  @address = current_user.build_address
end
```

And same in `create` action

More info [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference)